# Port windows API's from advapi32.dll to Linux in delphi

Tags: linux, delphi-10.4-sydney

I am having legacy code written in delphi over windows Platform which is now being migrated to Linux using delphi itself.

There the issue is in porting few functionalities from advapi32.dll  to Linux platform which  includes:
CryptAcquireContext
CryptImportKey
CryptSetKeyParam
CryptDestroyKey
CryptReleaseContext
CryptEncrypt
CryptDecrypt etc..

Can anyone suggest what is alternative library or any  other solution we could use for these set of API's on Linux?

Comment: Asking for recommendations is off-topic for StackOverflow. There are plenty of 3rd party cross-platform encryption libraries available for Delphi. Do some research and pick whatever suites your needs.